# showing quantity of items in cart in a custom magento 2 file does not work

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart

When I put the code to show the number of items in the cart in my custom headerfile.phtml it doesn't work, but when I access a checkout page it works perfectly, what to do?

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$cart = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
$itens = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsQty();
$itens = round($itens, 0);
if ($itens > 0)
echo $itens;
else 
echo 0;
?>
```

Comment: It will not work if the header is cached.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, you should take a reference of the below file. Here you can see all require variables and use them in your custom phtml file
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml:23

```
<!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
```

Please let me know if you this will not help.

Comment: put this code in my custom phtml and it didn't have any effect, is there something missing?

Comment: Copying this code will not work, you have to understand the logic that how it is implemented in the core mini cart.phtml file. I have provided references.